# Visual Studio Linker is using old/wrong filepath to link .lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, glew

My visual studio is using an old/wrong filepath to link glew even after I've specified the library path in the project settings.
I don't think it's a spelling issue because I've triple checked my spelling and the filepath that the linker complains about isn't used anywhere in the linker settings as far as I can tell.
I have looked online and it seems like nobody is having my problem.
I deleted the .suo file for visual studio to see if that would help, which it did not.

Any help/thoughts/criticisms welcome :(

[image: Picture of linker output]

[image: Additional Dependencies settings]

[image: Additional Libraries settings]

[image: Current File Explorer view of the lib]

Comment: Showing the picture seems appropriate, to demonstrate absence of copy-paste or typo errors. But for ease of reading, please show the relevant textual info also as text directly here.

Comment: Please also show the directory content of "one level up" , i.e. of the folder "Dependencies".

Comment: Did you try to do a "rebuild all"? Probably yes, but saying so explicity in the question would be clarifying.

Comment: Do you have different setting for "Debug" and "Release"?

Comment: Do you have different settings for "x64" and others? Like 32, or different architecture...

Comment: You say "old/wrong". Do I understand correctly, that the path in question has been meaningful/correct in the past? What did you change?

Comment: Sorry for listing obvious questions. I believe this is what you need. To find something obvious which you missed BECAUSE it is so obvious. (And I am not really fluent in MSVS, so they might even be wrong, too.)

Comment: Your path in the last screenshot has "3D-Game-Engine" twice. I assume that minor oddity is on purpose..

Comment: The path wasn't ever correct, I spelled dependencies incorrectly.  I don't have different settings for any platform/config, those settings are set for all platforms/configs.  I've rebuilt all.  I just can't get the linker to use the new path. :(

Comment: If I am extremely frustrated with a bug I sometimes resort to delete everything and start from scratch. Sometimes to the extend to uninstall all involved tools, reinstall and do everything again from an empty folder on the hard disk. You can of course backup your current work somewhere, to have it easier next with redoing steps, but do not copy any files, only compare them. Sorry if you have to resort to this, I only do it when I am very frustrated and at a complete loss. You should not get that desparate before 24h are passed for users in other time zones to chip in... Good luck.

Comment: Try opening your project file in a text editor and seeing if you can find the setting

Comment: > criticisms welcome: Don't lock yourself to VS, use an open standard to manage your project and be free to switch from/to VS IDE as needed. (cmake/qbs/similar).

Comment: I will put cmake on the list of things to learn.  I had been considering learning it since I see it absolutely everywhere.  I don't know what it is though, so a long way to go before I'll be using it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alan Birtles suggestion to open up the project file and edit the XML responsible for those settings directly fixed the problem.  I opened up the .vcxproj file with vscode and searched(ctrl+f) for the faulty pathways and deleted them.  This got rid of the linker error.